# I2C transmit with DMA and HAL not working

Tags: stm32, i2c, dma, hal

This seems to be a problem that is somewhat common, but I have been unsuccessful with any of the solutions I have found online. Specifically I am trying to transmit a 1024 byte buffer (full 128x64 px image) to a SSD1306 display via I2C/DMA and the HAL generated in cubeIDE. I am using a STML432 nucleo board. I have no problem transmitting the buffer without DMA using HAL_I2C_Mem_Write

Based on other questions I have seen, the problem lies in the fact that the DMA finishes while the I2C bus is still working on the transmit. I just don't know how to remedy this and the examples given usually don't use the HAL (unfortunately, despite my efforts I am not quite competent to correctly apply them to the HAL myself I guess). I have tried using the interrupts for I2c and DMA with no luck, only about the first 254 bytes get transferred (just shy of two rows showing on the screen).

Here is my code for sending the buffer:

```
static void ssd1306_WriteMData_DMA(const uint8_t *data, uint16_t size)
{
    while(HAL_I2C_GetState(&hi2c1) != HAL_I2C_STATE_READY);
    HAL_I2C_Mem_Write_DMA(&hi2c1, I2C_ADDR, SSD1306_REG_MDAT, 1, (uint8_t*)data, size);
}
```

and the code for each interrupt handler:

```
void I2C1_EV_IRQHandler(void)
{
  /* USER CODE BEGIN I2C1_EV_IRQn 0 */
    if(I2C1->ISR & I2C_ISR_TCR){
        
    I2C1->CR2 |=  (I2C_CR2_STOP);// stop i2c
    I2C1->ICR |=  (I2C_ICR_STOPCF);// Reset the ICR  flag.

    // stop DMA
    DMA1->IFCR |= DMA_IFCR_CTCIF6;
    // clear flag
    DMA1_Channel6->CCR &= ~DMA_CCR_EN;
}
  /* USER CODE END I2C1_EV_IRQn 0 */
  //HAL_I2C_EV_IRQHandler(&hi2c1);
  /* USER CODE BEGIN I2C1_EV_IRQn 1 */
 
  /* USER CODE END I2C1_EV_IRQn 1 */
}


void DMA1_Channel6_IRQHandler(void)
{
  /* USER CODE BEGIN DMA1_Channel6_IRQn 0 */

    // stop DMA
    DMA1->IFCR |= DMA_IFCR_CTCIF6;
    // clear flag
    DMA1_Channel6->CCR &= ~DMA_CCR_EN;

  /* USER CODE END DMA1_Channel6_IRQn 0 */
  HAL_DMA_IRQHandler(&hdma_i2c1_tx);
  /* USER CODE BEGIN DMA1_Channel6_IRQn 1 */

  /* USER CODE END DMA1_Channel6_IRQn 1 */
}
```

I think that is all the pertinent code, let me know if there is something else I am missing. All of the initialization code for the peripherals was done through cubeMX, but I can post that if need be, or the settings. I feel like it is something really simple that I'm missing, but this is a bit over my head to be honest so I don't quite grasp exactly what's going on...

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Problem is in your custom `DMA1_Channel6_IRQHandler` and `I2C1_EV_IRQHandler`. Those functions will be called right after I2C transfers 255 bytes, which is MAX_NBYTE_SIZE for NBYTES. HAL already have all required interrupt routines inside `stm32l4xx_hal_i2c.c`:

1. Sets I2C transfer IRQ handler to `I2C_Master_ISR_DMA`;
2. Checks if data size is larger than 255 bytes and uses reload mode.
3. Sets I2C DMA complete callback to `I2C_DMAMasterTransmitCplt`;
4. Starts DMA using `HAL_DMA_Start_IT()`
5. Configures I2C registers using `I2C_TransferConfig()`

HAL driver will handle all I2C+DMA interrupts using `I2C_Master_ISR_DMA` and `I2C_DMAMasterTransmitCplt`:

1. `I2C_DMAMasterTransmitCplt` will restart DMA for each chunk of 255 (MAX_NBYTE_SIZE) or less bytes.
2. `I2C_Master_ISR_DMA` will reset RELOAD/NBYTES registers using `I2C_TransferConfig`.
   For last block of data `I2C_AUTOEND_MODE` is used.

So all you need is

1. remove "user code" from `DMA1_Channel6_IRQHandler` and `I2C1_EV_IRQHandler` functions
2. enable I2C1 event interrupt in STM32 Device Configuration Tool
3. configure DMA with data width byte/byte
4. perform a single call of `HAL_I2C_Mem_Write_DMA(...)` to start transfer
5. check HAL_I2C_STATE_READY before next transfer

See `HAL_I2C_Mem_Write_DMA`, `I2C_Master_ISR_DMA` and `I2C_DMAMasterTransmitCplt` source code in `stm32l4xx_hal_i2c.c` to understand how it works.

About why DMA finishes while I2C is still working: HAL driver sends I2C data over DMA using 255 byte chunks, stops DMA, starts DMA, clears I2C_CR2 NBYTES/RELOAD, enables DMA. **DMA may be run continuously using DMA_CIRCULAR mode, but currently it is not implemented in HAL I2C drivers.** Here is example of using I2C with DMA_CIRCULAR mode:

```cpp
// DMA enabled single time
hi2c1.hdmatx->XferCpltCallback =  MY_I2C_DMAMasterTransmitCplt;
HAL_DMA_Start_IT(hi2c1.hdmatx, (uint32_t)&i2cBuffer, (uint32_t)&hi2c1.Instance->TXDR, I2C_BUFFER_SIZE);
MY_I2C_TransferConfig(&hi2c1,  (uint16_t)DAC_ADDR, 254, I2C_RELOAD_MODE, I2C_GENERATE_START_WRITE); // in first call using I2C_GENERATE_START_WRITE
uint32_t tmpisr = I2C_IT_TCI; 
__HAL_I2C_ENABLE_IT(&hi2c1, tmpisr);
hi2c1.Instance->CR1 |= I2C_CR1_TXDMAEN;
```

Still need to clear I2C_CR2 NBYTES/RELOAD using `MY_I2C_TransferConfig` each 254 bytes (I do not use 255 to align interrupt firing to even index in array):

```cpp
static HAL_StatusTypeDef MY_I2C_Master_ISR_DMA(struct __I2C_HandleTypeDef *hi2c, uint32_t ITFlags, uint32_t ITSources)
{
    if (__HAL_I2C_GET_FLAG(&hi2c1, I2C_FLAG_TCR) == SET)
    {
        MY_I2C_TransferConfig(&hi2c1,  (uint16_t)DAC_ADDR, 254, I2C_RELOAD_MODE, I2C_NO_STARTSTOP); // in repeated calls using I2C_NO_STARTSTOP
    
    }
    return HAL_OK;
}
```

With this approach DMA circular buffer size is not limited to 255 bytes:

```cpp
#define I2C_BUFFER_SIZE 1024
uint8_t i2cBuffer[I2C_BUFFER_SIZE];
```

Main.c should have `MY_I2C_TransferConfig()` function, which is copy pasted version of private function `HAL_I2C_TransferConfig()` from `stm32l4xx_hal_i2c.c`. On earlier STM32 microcontrollers there is no NBYTES/RELOAD fields and `I2C_CR2` does not need to be updated this way.
Using DMA in circular mode allows to achieve highest frame rate, you just need to fill DMA buffers in time using `XferHalfCpltCallback` and `XferCpltCallback` callbacks. Frames may be copied from larger buffer by using `memcpy()` or DMA MEMTOMEM transfer.

Comment: Thank you, I believe this was exactly what I ended up stumbling uppon! I seem to recall I also had some code in the wrong IRQ handler that was clearing a flag or something. That was throwing me off the trail. I think I mistakenly put it there because I went full potato on the generated names and mistook one for the other. Eventually I did get it working though but I really appreciate you taking the time for this detailed explanation for me and anyone else having this issue! Thank you!

Comment: I've created same I2C DMA but despite NVIC being activated the interrupt call doesn't happen and no transmission occur at all can you please see my question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70420672/hal-library-cant-handle-dma-i2c

Answer (score 1):

You haven't said which STM32 you are using.  They have different bit definitions (because the I2C peripherals in the earlier released parts were rubbish) but it looks like you are using one of the later ones.

Basically you can find what you need in the bit definitions for the I2C registers in the reference manual.  If you are setting stop before it has finished you need to look for a BUSY bit that gets cleared or BTF (byte transfer finished) bit that gets set when it is time for you to send stop.

Comment: Oops, I meant to put that in and have now edited. It is a STM32L432 on a nucleo board. I recognize the BTF from some other pages I have read, can you explain a little more? In which interrupt do I need to wait for the BTF/BUSY and which am I telling to stop (I2C or DMA)? Thanks!

Comment: I haven't use the L4 but from a quick look at the manual it looks like you need to enable the transfer complete interrupt with TCIE bit, but note that the NBYTES field is only 8 bits so you will need perhaps 4 TC interrupts to transfer with the RELOAD bit set transferring 255 bytes each and then one more to do the last 4 bytes.  You can probably do without the DMA complete interrupt in that case. (BTF is a name used in other older parts that don't have the NBYTES functionality).

Comment: OK, I think I am on the verge of understanding, I have been stepping through HAL_I2C_Mem_Write_DMA and it seems to be doing what you are saying with regards to setting xfermode = I2C_RELOAD_MODE; and it stored and decrements the number of bytes in hi2c->XferCount, it seems like it is all setup to loop until XferCount is 0, but it only runs through once, then calls the I2C1_EV_IRQHandler abov. At that point if I check RESET = 1 and NBYTES = 255. How do I get it to actually loop back through and finish? do I need to set START to 1? Pg 1182 says START has no effect if RESET is set... Thanks!

Comment: I have tried setting START to 1 with no effect, and if I clear NBYTES and set it to 255, it clears the I2C_ISR_TCR flag, but it still never seems to trigger sending the next bytes... I feel like the HAL should be taking care of this, as it seems to be set up that way in HAL_I2C_Mem_Write_DMA. Maybe I just have a configuration setting wrong and that is causing it to hang?